# Parse Array with respect to colon in jolt transforms processor in Apache Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

How to parse or split an array with respect to colon(s) in jolt transformation processor in Apache NiFi.

**input:**

```json
{
  "metricname": [
    "CPU1min",
    "MemoryFree",
    "MemoryUsed"
  ],
  "dataSourceName": "Standard CPU Utilization Network Cisco",
  "paramname": {
    "Standard CPU Utilization Network Cisco-3745 chassis Index0": {
      "values": [
        [
          "No Data",
          "No Data",
          "No Data",
          "No Data",
          "No Data"
        ],
        [
          "No Data",
          "No Data",
          "No Data",
          "No Data",
          "No Data"
        ],
        [
          "No Data",
          "No Data",
          "No Data",
          "No Data",
          "No Data"
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**expected output:**

```json
[
  "metricname",
  [
    "CPU1min",
    "MemoryFree",
    "MemoryUsed"
  ],
  "dataSourceName",
  "Standard CPU Utilization Network Cisco",
  "paramname",
  "Standard CPU Utilization Network Cisco-3745 chassis Index0",
  "values",
  [
    "No Data",
    "No Data",
    "No Data",
    "No Data",
    "No Data"
  ],
  [
    "No Data",
    "No Data",
    "No Data",
    "No Data",
    "No Data"
  ],
  [
    "No Data",
    "No Data",
    "No Data",
    "No Data",
    "No Data"
  ]
]
```

please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: {
 
  "dataSourceName" : "Standard CPU Utilization Network Cisco",
  "paramname" : {
    "Standard CPU Utilization Network Cisco" : {
      "values" : [ [ "sathish", "No Data", "No Data",  "No Data" ], [ "No Data", "No Data", "No Data", "No Data", "No Data" ], [ "No Data", "No Data", "No Data", "No Data", "No Data" ], [ "3", "No Data", "No Data", "No Data", "No Data" ], [ "4", "No Data", "No Data", "No Data", "No Data" ], [ "No Data", "No Data", "No Data", "No Data", "No Data" ] ]
    }
  }
}

Comment: Expected Output:
{ "dataSourceName" , "Standard CPU Utilization Network Cisco", "paramname" ,  "Standard CPU Utilization Network Cisco" ,  "datasum : [0th, 3rd, 4th ]" }
We only need first array list in "values" field and position of list are 0Th , 3rd , 4Th and rest of data in "values" field should be  dropped

Comment: expected:[
  "dataSourceName",
  "Standard CPU Utilization Network Cisco",
  "paramname",
  "Standard CPU Utilization Network Cisco",
  "values",
  [
    "No Data",
    "No Data",
    "No Data"
  ],
  [
    "No Data",
    "No Data",
    "No Data",
    "No Data",
    "No Data"
  ],
  [
    "No Data",
    "No Data",
    "No Data",
    "No Data",
    "No Data"
  ],
  [
    "No Data",
    "No Data",
    "No Data",
    "No Data"
  ],
  [
    "No Data",
    "No Data",
    "No Data",
    "No Data"
  ]
]

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`"$"`** and **`"@"`** wildcards for generating key and value pairs, respectively within two successive **shift** transformations in order to get a unique array as result by melting down resembling stairs in shape such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "",
        "@": ""
      },
      "para*": {
        "$": "",
        "*": {
          "$": "",
          "*": {
            "$": "",
            "*": {
              "@": ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is:
[image]

Comment: i am so sorry to add this : My input is :{
  "metricname" : [ "CPU1min", "MemoryFree", "MemoryUsed" ],
  "dataSourceName" : "Standard CPU Utilization Network Cisco",
  "paramname" : {
    "Standard CPU Utilization Network Cisco-3745 chassis Index0" : {
      "values" : [ [ "No Data", "No Data", "No Data", "No Data", "No Data" ], [ "No Data", "No Data", "No Data", "No Data", "No Data" ], [ "No Data", "No Data", "No Data", "No Data", "No Data" ]]
    }
  }
}

Comment: Expected output:
[
  "metricname" , [ "CPU1min", "MemoryFree", "MemoryUsed" ],
  "dataSourceName" , "Standard CPU Utilization Network Cisco",
  "paramname" , 
    "Standard CPU Utilization Network Cisco-3745 chassis Index0" ,
      "values" ,  [ "No Data", "No Data", "No Data", "No Data", "No Data" ], [ "No Data", "No Data", "No Data", "No Data", "No Data" ], [ "No Data", "No Data", "No Data", "No Data", "No Data" ]
]

Comment: please help me out.